# How Jshell works without semicolon at end of line

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I'm new for java 9 and just practicing some snippet of code on jshell

```
 jshell> System.out.println("hello");
 hello

 jshell> System.out.println("hello")
 hello
```

In the both the cases I'm getting output of `hello` but `jshell` works without semicolon at end of line. I know java need semicolon

Answer (score 2):

`Jshell` adds the semicolon automatically . [Doc-Page-2-1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/JSHEL.pdf) or [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/jshell/snippets.htm#JSHEL-GUID-91924322-1F68-4E47-9AC6-CAD8A3114E21)

> Snippets of Java code are entered into JShell and immediately evaluated. Feedback about the results, actions performed, and any errors that occurred is shown

```
Note:

Terminating semicolons are automatically added to the end of a complete snippet if not entered.
```

Comment: Might want to look into the *JShell completion API* to make the answer more useful.

Comment: can you point me there @Naman you mean this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/package-summary.html

Comment: [`SourceCodeAnalysis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/SourceCodeAnalysis.Completeness.html) should be it precisely. This is though stated in the [JEP for Jshell](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222)